# Can't connect to router after turning off DHCP

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

So I was playing around with my router and dynamic/static IP addresses and after I tuned off the DHCP server of the Router I am no longer able to connect to the routers web interface even with a static IP.

The IP of the router is 10.0.0.138 and I also can configure a static IP on my Win7 like:
IP: 10.0.0.50
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 10.0.0.138
DNS: 10.0.0.138

so I can connect to the internet and ask a question on superuser.com but I am no longer able to connect to my router (connection refused) and undo my configurations?

Or is this a feature of thos cheap routers from the internet providers?

**NOTE:** I am connected via WLAN

Comment: Have you tried connecting with http://10.0.0.138 AND https://10.0.0.138. it's always worth checking if you can connect via https after changes

Comment: Many routers will allow you to disable access from the WLAN.  Did you perhaps change that setting as well?

Comment: good idea but no luck

Comment: no i havent configured anything other than DHCP but it could be that the default config wont allow access over WLAN ...

Comment: okay since my 10-years-old super-slow pc is the only device connected via cable I will come back and check this after sleep ^^

Comment: Try resetting the router. It will load its default settings and you should be able to access the routers web interface again. Only thing you will need to do is reconfigure the router once again after resetting it.

Comment: And remember to name the other users, or they will not be notified you are talking them, like @Abraxas.

Comment: @heavyd also no access over wired connection

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to reset the router.

There was no way for me to gain access to the router again after I disabled the router's DHCP server. Not via WLAN, cable, telepathy or all the known standard router IP addresses I have found on the web.